# How to wait for .forEach() to complete with sequence and order

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await

How to do this foreach one after the other?

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

        data.forEach((i) => {
            console.log(i)
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("hello")
            }, 500);
        })
```

`Output - 1, 2, 3, 4, hello, hello, hello, hello`

`expected output - 1, hello, 2, hello, 3, hello, 4, hello`

Comment: simple - you can't - setTimeout is asyncrhonous

Comment: Move `console.log(i)` into the callback given to `setTimeout`. This is not at all connected to async/await, though, since no promises are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can call inside setTimeout function to achieve result. But you have to wait for 500 miliseconds every time to call this:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

        data.forEach((i) => {
           
            setTimeout(() => { console.log(i);
                console.log("hello")
            }, 500);
        })
```

Output - 1, hello, 2, hello, 3, hello, 4, hello

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        data.forEach((i) => {
            console.log(i)
            console.log("hello")
        })
```

You can simply do this without using `setTimeout`